# How to run a python file taken as a parameter in a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, python

I have a basic script called `script.sh` which will take 3 parameters, each a python file. I need to run these programs within `script.sh`. I have

```
#! usr/bin/env python3
```

for my first line, and I've tried running each of the programs with `python ${1}` as well as `python3 ${1}`. I'm new to scripting; is it possible to run these programs within my script?

Comment: If the python scripts are marked executable, just call them by their name (no explicit python/python3) needed.

Comment: Is `script.sh` meant to be a shell script or a python script?

Comment: ```script.sh``` is a shell script. Also, when I removed the python/python3 and just had ```${1}``` it gives me a syntax error for that line.

Comment: If it's a shell script, then it should start with the shebang of a regular shell interpreter, such as `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`. The *shell* will then execute your python commands.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to add a slash to the start of the path, as in `#!/usr/bin/env python3`? The path must be reachable from the working directory, and having a `usr/bin/env` in a project is unlikely, to say the least.

---

As for how to run it: if you actually want to use the shebang line interpreter the file must be executable and you *must* run the script as just `/path/to/script.py` (or `./path/to/script.py`). As soon as you put a `python` or `python3` in front of the path *that* command is going to be used as the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to run python scripts via a shell script using shell CLAs you can try this one

```
#!/bin/bash

CLAString=$@ #Copying the CL arguments to a string

varlen=${#CLAString} #finding the no of CL args

if [[ $varlen -gt 0 ]] #if no of CL args is not zero
then
python ${1}.py # run first CLA python script
fi
```

execute this by ./script.sh file1 file2 file3